# Discussion Board view not working in custom master page - SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'RefreshCurrent' of undefined or null reference

Tags: error

Added Discussion board custom view to my custom page referring custom master page. It has reference to all inbuilt js files.

I get error when i try to click items like My discussion, Unanswered questions, it does not load and i get error "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'RefreshCurrent' of undefined or null reference". This works with seattle.master master page.